# LoadError: syntax: unexpected "end" in expression starting at untitled-

Tags: julia

I'm getting started with the Julia programming language and I'm not really understanding the "end" syntax.

```
function foo(s, d, m)
    res = 0
    for i in range(0,length(s)-m)
        tmp = 0
        for j in range(0,m)
            tmp += s[i+m]
        end
        if tmp == d
            res++            
        end
    end
    return res
end
```

Running this code I get

> LoadError: syntax: unexpected "end"
>   in expression starting at untitled-eae5b84e07787c95497e056f34423071:10

How should I fix my function?

Comment: Change `res++` to `res += 1` (assuming that `++` was intended to increase `res` by `1`). However, your code in general seems to have more problems. In particular you do not use `range` function correctly and it seems that you want to use `0`-based indexing and Julia uses `1`-based indexing. Can you please explain what you are trying to achieve - then I could give you a recommendation how to implement it.

Comment: Wait, are you saying that an array starts with the index one? Didn't know that, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Julia does not increment with res++. Instead, write
    res += 1